# Data processing in Kafka without Storm/Spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka

I am aware that one can use Storm or Spark streaming to do real time data processing with kafka but i want to ask if there is any functionality in kafka that is similar to Flume interceptor wherein data cleaning, etc can be done on the fly in an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is not such a feature in a released version of Kafka but the next release (0.10.0.0 according to [the roadmap](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Future+release+plan)) will have [Kafka Streams](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/streams) which looks to be similar to what you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Kafka Interceptors](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-42%3A+Add+Producer+and+Consumer+Interceptors) that are actually inspired in Flume Interceptor Interface. Like @Lundahl is pointing out the current version doesn't support this, but the next one will.